# php sqlsrv_connect set timeout?

Tags: php, sqlsrv

In my case, sometimes the database that php is trying to connect to might not exist, if it doesnt exist i want to `echo "Database doesnt exist";`

Is it possible to set a timeout in like 5 seconds, if the database doesnt exist becouse my script takes over 50 seconds to run? 
**It works but it takes too long to execute!**

```
$userID=$_SESSION['userID']; 
$serverName = ''; 
$uid = '';   
$pwd = '';
$database=$_SESSION['userID']; //sometimes correct database, other times 
                                 incorrect database  
$connectionInfo = array( "UID"=>$uid,                            
                         "PWD"=>$pwd,                            
                         "Database"=>$database); 

$conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo);
if(!$conn ) {
echo "invalid database name";
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

It won't tell you that the database doesn't exist, but there is a connection option for login timeout, which specifies the number of seconds to wait before failing the connection attempt.

You can use [`LoginTimeout`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/php/connection-options) in your connection options array like so:

```
$connectionInfo = array( "UID"=>$uid,                            
                         "PWD"=>$pwd,                            
                         "Database"=>$database,
                         "LoginTimeout" => 5);
```

Where `5` is the number of seconds you want the driver to wait before failing the attempt.

Comment: I added it, but still it seems to take over 50 seconds